# Proof of set of sequences of two symbols is similar to $(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, set-theory

I have been trying some questions on countability of sets.

Came across a question in which I had to show that the set of all sequences of $0$ and $1$ and the interval $(0,1)$ are similar.

It has been given to define a function as
$$ f:S \rightarrow (0,1)$$
$$ \text{as}\ f(<a_n>)=0._2a_1a_2a_3....$$ where $<a_n>=(a_1,a_2,...)$

Here $2$ in $0._2a_1a_2a_3...$ denotes the binary representation.

Here $S$ is the set of all sequences of $0$ and $1$ apart from the sequences $(0,0,0....)$ and $(1,1,1....)$.

We are adopting a rule such that every real number in $(0,1)$ is adopted uniquely.

I am supposed to prove that $f$ is bijective.

I have a problem in proving one-one.

Now since $f$ is a function and $(0,1,1,1...)$ and $(1,0,0,0...)$ belong to $S$.

By definition of $f$, they have images $0.0111..$ and $0.1000...$ which in binary represent the same number $\frac{1}{2}$.

Since we are taking a rule that implies that there exists only one representation of $\frac{1}{2}$, we can say that only one pre-image of $\frac{1}{2}$ say $(0,1,1...)$

But then what will be the image of $(1,0,0,....)$?. What number other than $\frac{1}{2}$ does $0.100..$ represent?

Basically, if I take $1/2$ to be a part of $[1/2,1]$..So what will $0.01111...$ represent?

Comment: There must be a mistake; this identification is bijective if you let $S$ be the set of sequences that don't end in an infinite sequence of $0$'s, and your image has to include the point $1 = 0._21111\dots$

Comment: Let us say we remove constant sequence (1,1,...) from S

Comment: Sure, then you still have to exclude sequences with an infinite tail of trailing $0$'s or else you'll keep running into the problem you're facing with injectivity since $0._2???01111\dots=0._2???10000\dots$

Comment: Are such removable sequences finite?

Comment: I'm saying the function $f$ as defined is not injective unless you shrink $S$ down. That being said, the subset of sequences that eventually end in a trailing sequence of $0$'s is countably infinite.

Comment: probably $S$ should be something like a quotient space over  the equivalence relation that identifies $10^{\infty}$ with $01^{\infty}$.